# Database CakePHP 3

Tags: database, cakephp-3.0

I want to make a database. The database is connected to a CakePHP 3.0 website
This is a school project where we need to make a question and answer system behind production lines.
There need to be a database where everything is stored.
The database needs to do something along the line like this:

- Each department has 1 or more machines under it.
- Each machine has a series of questions (1 or more) connected to it.
- And each question can only have 1 answer to it.

And I'm wondering if this is the right way for Cake 3.0 or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Database modeling has nothing to do with your PHP framework. Just model your database as you want, and use your framework to play with it.

Comment: @Pierre-LoupPagniez That's not necessarily correct. Many frameworks do at least suggest specific design and naming conventions in order to ease the workflow, or support specific ORM functionality. So it's advised to study the frameworks documentation and take that into account.

Comment: @tribeldragon Your question is kinda offtopic, as it's not directly programming related, and very broad since nobody knows the exact requirements of your project. General data modeling questions do usually fit better on http://dba.stackexchange.com As mentioned in my previous comment, I'd suggest that you study the CakePHP docs with regards to conventions, and take them into account accordingly.

Comment: @ndm okey thank you very much